# unique_ptr to a concrete type

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, unique-ptr, object-lifetime

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

class Concrete
{
public:
    void Bar() { std::cout << "concrete" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Concrete> ConcretePtr = nullptr;
    ConcretePtr->Bar();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> BasePtr;
    BasePtr->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I assume declaring a unique_ptr to a concrete type `Concrete`, allocates memory for an object of type `Concrete` and the unique_ptr starts pointing to it. Is my assumption/understanding correct ? I ask because `ConcretePtr->Bar();` prints "concrete" to the console. But, if I make a unique pointer to an interface `Base`, it does not know the exact type of object that I need and does not allocate/acquire resources in the memory.

This fails at `BasePtr->foo();` with `BasePtr._Mypair._Myval2 was nullptr.`

Why does the first declaration `std::unique_ptr<Concrete> ConcretePtr = nullptr;` allocate an object by itself ? what if I did not want it to be pointing to some real object at that very line of code, but wanted only a smart pointer ?

Now if I change the declaration to be `std::unique_ptr<Concrete> ConcretePtr;` and the `Concrete` type to be the following,

```
class Concrete
{
    int ConcreteNum;
public:
    void Bar() 
    { 
        std::cout << "concrete" << std::endl; 
        ConcreteNum = 38;
        std::cout << ConcreteNum << std::endl;
    }
};
```

it fails at `ConcreteNum = 38;` complaining that `this` was `nullptr`; if this `this` was `nullptr` then why and how did the earlier call (where `Concrete` did not have any state `ConcreteNum`) to `Bar` work ?

Moreover why does it not fail at `ConcretePtr->Bar();` (this `->` requires a concrete object, does it not ? what was `this` here ?) but inside `Bar`, in that assignment ?

I see the same issue with `std::shared_ptr` as well. I'm not very sure of the difference between declaration, initialization & assignment. Please help me understand.

I'm using MSVC.

Comment: no, you need to allocate the memory that unique_ptr points to `std::unique_ptr<Concrete> ConcretePtr(new Concrete)` you are experiencing undefined behavior.

Comment: No object of `Concrete` is created in your first example. You can firstly learn about [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). In short, undefined behavior can do anything, thus **may** have the expected output in your first example.

Comment: @Praetorian the first `ConcretePtr->Bar();` works correctly. It prints "Concrete" to the console. what was `this` here ? how could `ConcretePtr->Bar();` work if `this` was nullptr ?

Comment: Pointers are separate to what they point at... creating a pointer doesn't create anything to point at

Comment: Nothing in `Bar()` requires dereferencing `this`, the compiler probably inlines its contents and never dereferences the nullptr. It's undefined behavior even though it doesn't crash.

Comment: @user3222 "Appears to work" is a possible (and very devious) form of Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    std::unique_ptr<Concrete> ConcretePtr = nullptr;
```

> I assume declaring a unique_ptr to a concrete type Concrete, allocates memory for an object of type Concrete and the unique_ptr starts pointing to it. Is my assumption/understanding correct ?

Well, you can trivially check. Write a default constructor for `Concrete` that prints something out so you can tell when an instance is created. Run the smallest possible program (just the line above in `main`). Did you see the expected output?

You should be checking this stuff *before* asking a question (and probably after reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)), but to save you time: **no**, that line doesn't construct an object of type `Concrete`.

You can also check explicitly whether `unique_ptr` is managing an object, with

```
if (!ConcretePtr) {
  std::cout << "ConcretePtr doesn't point to anything\n";
} else {
  std::cout << "ConcretePtr owns an object\n";
}
```

This check is also trivial, and you could easily do it before asking a question.

> I ask because `ConcretePtr->Bar();` prints "concrete" to the console

This is a bad test because if the pointer *is* a `nullptr`, it's undefined behaviour. If you care whether the pointer is a `nullptr`, you should check that explicitly *before* dereferencing it, as above.

To demonstrate *why* this test is confusing you (and you should use the ones above in preference), consider a likely implementation of non-virtual member functions (recall they get an implicit `this` pointer):

```
// void Concrete::Bar() implemented as
void Concrete_Bar(Concrete *this)

// and ConcretePtr->Bar() implemented as
Concrete_Bar(ConcretePtr.get());
```

so, you just passed a `nullptr` to a function that ignores its only parameter, and you never tested the thing you thought you did.

Comment: Thanks Useless. It was very helpful. Where should I learn about such implementations of `Concrete::Bar()` and `ConcretePtr->Bar()` ? But, as you mentioned I could have checked with a squawking default constructor at least. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd advise focusing on learning how to use the things that _are_ defined first, they're also generally well-documented. Knowing why your undefined behaviour did a particular thing is probably less useful than knowing that it _is_ undefined, and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

The `unique_ptr` models a pointer. That is, it's an object that points to another object.

Initialising the `unique_ptr` with nullptr creates it in the state where it is not pointing to or owning another object.

It's like saying `Concrete* p = nullptr`.

Initialise it in one of these ways:

```
std::unique_ptr<Concrete> p{new Concrete()};
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<Concrete> p;  // = nullptr is implied.
p.reset(new Concrete());
```

or, better:

```
std::unique_ptr<Concrete> p = std::make_unique<Concrete>();
```

or simply:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<Concrete>();
```

But be careful in this case if you really want to be pointing to the Base interface:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> p = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> p = nullptr;

p = std::make_unique<Derived>();  // assignment from rvalue ref of compatible unique_ptr.
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I did not call for allocation myself with `new` `make_unique` or `make_shared`, I think that I should be experiencing undefined behavior as others pointed out.